# SML: map function on list with a function that takes more than 1 argument

Tags: list, dictionary, sml

I have a list of N elements in SML.

I want to apply a function to every element in that list, so I use map.

However the function I want to apply has more than 1 argument like this:

```
 foo a b (c, d)
```

Where a is the element I am using from the list and b c and d are predefined variables that are the same every time.

I declare my function like this:

```
 fun foo2 = map foo aList b (c,d)
```

but I get an operator and operand error, which was expected but I can think of any other way to do this.

Comment: Your `foo2` function seems to be missing arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be most convenient if the order of foo's args were changed; you can, of course, make a wrapper:

```
fun foo_swapped_args b (c,d) a = foo a b (c, d)
```

Then you could do

```
map (foo_swapped_args b (c,d)) aList
```

Answer (score 6):

```
fun foo2 list = map (fn x => foo x b (c, d)) list
```